# jQuery select two and only two checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I'm working on a solution that will compare two rows in a table. The most basic table structure is illustrated below:

```
<table id="historyTable">
   <tr>
     <td><input type="checkbox" id="row_0" /></td>
     <td>same</td>
     <td>r0c2</td>
     <td>r0c3</td>
     <td>r0c4</td>
     <td>r0c5</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><input type="checkbox" id="row_1" /></td>
      <td>same</td>
      <td>same</td>
      <td>r1c3-different</td>
      <td>same</td>
      <td>same</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><input type="checkbox" id="row_2" /></td>
      <td>same</td>
      <td>same</td>
      <td>r2c3</td>
      <td>same</td>
      <td>same</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

This will be populated from a database, so, obviously there's going to be `n` number of rows, but each row will add a checkbox to the DOM using the naming convention hard-coded in the example above.

I thought that the "hard part" was going to be highlighting the different cell values - turns out, that was easy. The hard part is working with the checkboxes to insure that two, and only two, are selected.

I tried using various takes on `.each("td").is(":checked").id` which did a good job of getting me the `id` property of the checked checkboxes, but I have no idea on how to limit the selection to two selections.

The idea is once the second checkbox is checked, a function fires to highlight the differences in the selected rows.

Could someone please nudge me in a direction to accomplish the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [Demo](http://codepen.io/hotdudehvfun/pen/ZLOqMG?editors=1010) here

```
    <table id="historyTable">
   <tr>
     <td><input type="checkbox" id="row_0" /></td>
     <td>same</td>
     <td>r0c2</td>
     <td>r0c3</td>
     <td>r0c4</td>
     <td>r0c5</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><input type="checkbox" id="row_1" /></td>
      <td>same</td>
      <td>same</td>
      <td>r1c3-different</td>
      <td>same</td>
      <td>same</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><input type="checkbox" id="row_2" /></td>
      <td>same</td>
      <td>same</td>
      <td>r2c3</td>
      <td>same</td>
      <td>same</td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
     <td><input type="checkbox" id="row_3" /></td>
      <td>same</td>
      <td>same</td>
      <td>r2c3</td>
      <td>same</td>
      <td>same</td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
     <td><input type="checkbox" id="row_4" /></td>
      <td>same</td>
      <td>same</td>
      <td>r2c3</td>
      <td>same</td>
      <td>same</td>
   </tr>
</table>
<p id='output'></p>


    var inputs=document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT');
var limit=2;
var count=0;
for(input of inputs)
 {
    input.addEventListener("change",function(e){
      restrictLimit(e);
    });
 }
function restrictLimit(e)
{
  if(e.target.checked==true)
  {
    count++;
    if(count>limit)
      {
        e.target.checked=false;
        count=limit;
      }
  }
    else
    {
      count--;  
    }
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML="Checkbox Selected:"+count;
}
```

Comment: Arun - I can work with that. A little count-intuitive to the user when they try to select > 2, but I can easily add some feedback to let them know they broke the rules rather than just making them wonder why they're clicking on a checkbox and it won't select. Thanks for the nudge!

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `.is(":checked")` on a `<td>`, it has to be done on the checkbox inside the `<td>`. And `.each()` requires a function argument to execute on each element.

But the easy way is to select all the checked boxes, and count them with `.length`.

```
if ($("td :checkbox:checked").length == 2) {
    // do stuff
} else {
    alert("Check exactly 2 rows");
}
```

Comment: I was also able to get the count by using `$("input:checkbox:checked").length` which, if they weren't the only checkboxes on the screen would not be an accurate count of what I wanted, but in this case, it was acceptable. Thanks for the help...my brain was in bad shape yesterday by the time I reached out to SO for help!